# If I own the patent to A+B+C, and later A+B is granted a patent, can I still manufacture A+B+C

Tags: patent-infringement, prior-art

If I manufacture `A+B+C`, then I would be infringing upon `A+B`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A patent on an invention gives you no right to make it.**

It is a common and persistent mis understanding. Patents convey the negative right to try to stop others from practicing your invention but rights to *do* anything.

There can be many reasons why you couldn’t make something you patented. It might be covered by others patents it could be illegal, etc.

For for specific question A B C should not have been granted if A B is known, let alone patented, as you can see from your two or three other questions.

Comment: But the assumption is that A B C came before A B, which is why it was patented.